# A quadratic polynomial $f$ such that $f\circ f' = f'\circ f$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, function-and-relation-composition

> Given that $\ f\left( x \right)=ax^{2}+bx+c$, find a value for each of
>   $a, b$ and $c$ such that: $f\left( f'\left( x \right) \right)=f'\left(
>  f\left( x \right) \right)$.

---

What I did:

$$a=b=c=0\; ∴\; f\left( x \right)=0\; and\; f'\left( x \right)=0\; ∴\; f\left( f'\left( x \right) \right)=f'\left( f\left( x \right) \right)$$

Is this a feasible answer?

Comment: Yes your answer is feasible.

Comment: all i needed, thanks

Comment: It may not be welcome, but it's feasible. Suppose there's a further requirement that $a \neq 0$?

Comment: If $f=0$, how is it a quadratic polynomial? If your heading is wrong it works. Nice try though...+1

Answer (score 1):

HINT: we have $$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c\implies f'(x)=2ax+b$$ $$f(f'(x))=a(2ax+b)^2+b(2ax+b)+c$$ &
$$f'(f(x))=2a(ax^2+bx+c)+b$$
hence, $$a(2ax+b)^2+b(2ax+b)+c=2a(ax^2+bx+c)+b$$